# The signed build is constant (not updating) whereas the unsigned build is fine

Tags: react-native

I am working running an existing react-native project which is 3 years old. When I make a change in the labels or texts, the changes appear in the debug build but signed build is always constant. When I run the following command, a constant build is formed without image

> cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && npx react-native run-android --variant=release

[image: screen without image]

But when I run the following command in the same project, a debug build is formed with images

> npx react-native run-android

[image: screen with images]
Of the same code I changed the spellings of label Register to Registered, the changes appeared in the debug build but not in the signed build. Any help would be highly appreciated. Lots of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all find the below files and delete them:

> android/app/scr/main/assets/index.android.*

Secondly run the following command in the project root directory:

> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res